# IllegalStateException Error in Service class

Tags: android

I am working on `service` in `android` but I am facing an error which is

```
  Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: GoogleApiClient is not connected yet.
            at com.google.android.gms.common.api.zzf.zzb(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.common.api.zzg.zzb(Unknown Source)
            at com.google.android.gms.location.internal.zzd.requestLocationUpdates(Unknown Source)
            at com.example.mine4.newapp.MyService.startLocationUpdates(MyService.java:180)
            at com.example.mine4.newapp.MyService.togglePeriodicLocationUpdates(MyService.java:123)
            at com.example.mine4.newapp.MyService.onCreate(MyService.java:62)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2716)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:165)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1455)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5391)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

and my code is here:

```
public class MyService extends Service implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {

    private static final String TAG = MyService.class.getSimpleName();

    private final static int PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 1000;

    private Location mLastLocation;

    // Google client to interact with Google API
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    // boolean flag to toggle periodic location updates
    private boolean mRequestingLocationUpdates = false;

    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;

    // Location updates intervals in sec
    private static int UPDATE_INTERVAL = 10000; // 10 sec
    private static int FATEST_INTERVAL = 5000; // 5 sec
    private static int DISPLACEMENT = 10; // 10 meters


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        if (checkPlayServices()) {

            // Building the GoogleApi client
            buildGoogleApiClient();

            createLocationRequest();
        }
        displayLocation();
        togglePeriodicLocationUpdates();
    }
    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        super.onStart(intent, startId);
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }

//    @Override
//    protected void onResume() {
//        super.onResume();
//
//        checkPlayServices();
//
//        // Resuming the periodic location updates
//        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected() && mRequestingLocationUpdates) {
//            startLocationUpdates();
//        }
//    }
//
//    @Override
//    protected void onStop() {
//        super.onStop();
//        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
//            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
//        }
//    }
//    @Override
//    protected void onPause() {
//        super.onPause();
//        stopLocationUpdates();
//    }

    /**
     * Method to display `location` on UI
     * */
    private void displayLocation() {

        mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi
                .getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

        if (mLastLocation != null) {
            double latitude = mLastLocation.getLatitude();
            double longitude = mLastLocation.getLongitude();



        } else {
        }
    }
    private void togglePeriodicLocationUpdates() {
        if (!mRequestingLocationUpdates) {
            // Changing the button text



            mRequestingLocationUpdates = true;

            // Starting the location updates
            startLocationUpdates();

            Log.d(TAG, "Periodic location updates started!");

        } else {
            // Changing the button text



            mRequestingLocationUpdates = false;

            // Stopping the location updates
            stopLocationUpdates();

            Log.d(TAG, "Periodic location updates stopped!");
        }
    }
    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API).build();
    }

    /**
     * Creating location request object
     * */
    protected void createLocationRequest() {
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FATEST_INTERVAL);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(DISPLACEMENT);
    }


    private boolean checkPlayServices() {
        int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)) {
                GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorString(resultCode);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "This device is not supported.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();

            }
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Starting the location updates
     * */
    protected void startLocationUpdates() {

        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);

    }

    /**
     * Stopping location updates
     */
    protected void stopLocationUpdates() {
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(
                mGoogleApiClient, this);
    }

    /**
     * Google api callback methods
     */
    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Connection failed: ConnectionResult.getErrorCode() = "
                + result.getErrorCode());
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {

        // Once connected with google api, get the location
        displayLocation();

        if (mRequestingLocationUpdates) {
            startLocationUpdates();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int arg0) {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // Assign the new location
        mLastLocation = location;

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Location changed!",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        // Displaying the new location on UI
        displayLocation();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

    }
    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }
}
```

and error is here:

```
protected void startLocationUpdates() {

    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
            mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);

}
```

I am first time using service and I need to work my service like my gps locator which work on background.

Answer (score 0):

Simply, you need to uncomment the following part which is responsible for connecting to the Google API when the `service` or the `activity` starts and stop `onStop()`

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    checkPlayServices();

    // Resuming the periodic location updates
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected() && mRequestingLocationUpdates) {
        startLocationUpdates();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    stopLocationUpdates();
}
```

Comment: At least the `onResume` and `onStop` are a must. You have to uncomment them and deal with the error. @ChaudryJunaidSaifUllahChadh